# $\lim_{x\to\infty} x^2\operatorname{cos}\left(\frac{3x+2}{x^2}-1\right)$ without using L’Hôpital.

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

Can I calculate the following limit without applying L'Hôpital?

> $$\lim_{x\to\infty} x^2\operatorname{cos}\left(\frac{3x+2}{x^2}-1\right)$$

With L'Hôpital it gives me as a result $\frac{-9}{2}$.

Comment: *How* did you apply L'Hopital rule here?

Comment: You've mistyped the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think he want to type and solve this $$\lim_{x\to\infty} x^2(cos(\frac{3x+2}{x^2})-1)=\frac{-9}{2}$$ this can be solve by multiplying conjugate 
$$\quad{\lim_{x\to\infty} x^2(cos(\frac{3x+2}{x^2})-1)=\\
\lim_{x\to\infty} x^2(cos(\frac{3x+2}{x^2})-1)\times \frac{cos(\frac{3x+2}{x^2})+1}{cos(\frac{3x+2}{x^2})+1}=\\
\lim_{x\to\infty} x^2(-\sin^2(\frac{3x+2}{x^2}))\times \frac{1}{cos(\frac{3x+2}{x^2})+1}=\\}$$ 
as $x\to \infty \implies \sin(\frac{3x+2}{x^2})\to 0 \implies \sin(\frac{3x+2}{x^2})\sim \frac{3x+2}{x^2}\\$so 
$$\quad{\lim_{x\to\infty} x^2(-\sin^2(\frac{3x+2}{x^2}))\times \frac{1}{cos(\frac{3x+2}{x^2})+1}=\\
\lim_{x\to\infty} -x^2(\frac{3x+2}{x^2})^2\times \frac{1}{cos(\frac{3x+2}{x^2})+1}=\\
\lim_{x\to\infty} -(\frac{(3x+2)^2}{x^2})\times \frac{1}{cos(\frac{3x+2}{x^2})+1}=\\\lim_{x\to\infty} -(\frac{9x^2+12x+4}{x^2})\times \frac{1}{cos(\frac{3x+2}{x^2})+1}=\\
\lim_{x\to\infty} -(\frac92)\times \frac{1}{cos(\frac{3x+2}{x^2})+1}=\\
 -(\frac92)\times \frac{1}{cos(0)+1}=\\\frac{-9}{2}}$$

Comment: @trick15f :please look at my answer !>?

Comment: @MariosGretsas : I saw the question , I saw the answer $\frac{-9}{2}$ and then think ,may be this

Comment: @Khosrotash thank you very much, I understood everything

Comment: @trick15f : please explain How you do a mistake in writing question  !

Answer (score 0):

Since
$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \operatorname{cos}\left(\frac{3x+2}{x^2}-1\right)=\cos1>0,$$
we obtain

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} x^2\operatorname{cos}\left(\frac{3x+2}{x^2}-1\right)=+\infty$$

Maybe do you mean 
$$\lim_{x\to\infty} x^2\operatorname{cos}\left(\frac{3x+2}{x^2}-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)=\infty?$$

Comment: You used that $f(x)=\cos x$ is an even and continuous function. $$\lim_{x\to \infty}\left(\frac{3x+2}{x^2}-1\right)=$$

$$=\lim_{x\to \infty}\left(\frac{\frac{3}{x}+\frac{2}{x^2}}{1}-1\right)=$$

$$=\frac{0+0}{1}-1=0-1=-1$$

and $\cos (-1)=\cos 1$.

Comment: @user236182 Yes of course!

Answer (score 0):

We have to find the limit of :

$$\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}x^2(cos(\frac{ax+b}{x^2})-1)=?$$

If we put the substitution $x=\frac{1}{y}$ and use the formula $1-2sin(x)^2=cos(2x)$ we get :
$$\lim\limits_{y \to 0}\frac{-2sin(\frac{(ay+by^2)}{2})^2}{y^2}$$
Wich equivalent to :
$$\lim\limits_{y \to 0}\frac{(ay+by^2)^2}{4}\frac{-2sin(\frac{(ay+by^2)}{2})^2}{y^2\frac{(ay+by^2)^2}{4}}$$
Or 
$$\lim\limits_{y \to 0}\frac{-sin(\frac{(ay+by^2)}{2})^2}{\frac{(ay+by^2)^2}{4}}=-1$$
Because : $\lim\limits_{z \to 0}\frac{sin(z)}{z}=1$

So we have :

$$\lim\limits_{y \to 0}\frac{(ay+by^2)^2}{4}\frac{-2sin(\frac{(ay+by^2)}{2})^2}{y^2\frac{(ay+by^2)^2}{4}}=\lim\limits_{y \to 0}\frac{(ay+by^2)^2}{4}\frac{-2}{y^2}=\frac{-a^2}{2}$$